# How to get dump of database if I only have select privileges on it

Tags: mysql

How to get dump of database if I only have select privileges on it. It is giving access denied error when I am running mysqldump command.

I am getting following error:
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'sangeeta'@'%' to database 'abc' when doing LOCK TABLES

Thanks!!

Comment: SELECT privileges should be enough. Check your credentials.

Comment: I tried multiple time but not working, I am able to log in mysql and run select query but not able to get the dump. Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like your out of luck! Contact your webhost

Comment: @Sangeeta Try adding `--skip-lock-tables` to your mysqldump call.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. You really get an access denied error. Error message is clear, you don't have select privileges.
2. You get a message that you don't have the privilege to lock the tables.

Solutions for number 2:

Use the `--lock-tables=false` option for non-InnoDB tables or the `--single-transaction` option for InnoDB tables.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you would tell us the exact error message!

Comment: It is giving error :  
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line
1 (1064)